# Setting $scope property value through iteration over array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build out my first Angular app and having an issue with this:

```
(function() {

var ItemController = function($scope, $routeParams, $log, foodFactory) {
    var foodId = $routeParams.foodId;
    $scope.food = [];
    $scope.item;

    function init() {
        foodFactory.getFoods()
            .success(function(foods) {
                $scope.food = foods;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               //handle error
            });
    }

    init();

    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.food.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (foodId == $scope.food[i].id) {
            $scope.item = $scope.food[i];
        }
    }

};
angular.module('paleoApp')
    .controller('ItemController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$log', 'foodFactory', ItemController]);

})();
```

The code properly sets $scope.food to the array of objects pulled from a JSON file by foodFactory, and the view also properly displays the array when {{ food }} is used. In order to get the proper object within the array, I tried looping through $scope.food to find the object with property 'id' that matches foodId in order to assign that object to $scope.item. However, the view won't display anything for {{ item }}.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the init method, the getFoods() call appears to be asynchronous, but you are iterating through `$scope.food` prior to the call finishing. You should be able to do something like the following:

```
var ItemController = function($scope, $routeParams, $log, foodFactory) {
    var foodId = $routeParams.foodId;
    $scope.food = [];
    $scope.item;

    function init() {
        return foodFactory.getFoods()
            .success(function(foods) {
                $scope.food = foods;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               //handle error
            });
    }

    init().then(function() {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.food.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (foodId == $scope.food[i].id) {
                $scope.item = $scope.food[i];
            }
        }
    });
};
```

What you have here is the init method returns a promise. When you call `init().then` you wait until `$scope.food = foods;` has executed before finding the food item in the list.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense to me. Unfortunately, it doesn't allow me to use .then() like that. I did make a small work-around using $timeout which got me the results I wanted, but it feels like a cheap hack and I want to figure out how to do this properly.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Angular's $http service to fetch the JSON file. Note that I changed the `init` method to return a promise (previously it was not doing so).

A [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) call will return a promise with success/error methods, The success/error methods will both return promises of their own for chaining. In this way you can return the promise from the call to .error, and chain it like in my example above.